# What are the requirements for a custom type to work with boost::format's % operator?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I would like to know what function/s and/or operators must be implemented within a class to work with the `boost::format` `%` operator.

For example:

```
class A
{
    int n;
    // <-- What additional operator/s and/or function/s must be provided?
}

A a;
boost::format f("%1%");
f % a;
```

I have been studying [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers), which is related in some ways to my question, but this has sent me into days of related review and learning regarding issues involving `auto` and various other language features.  I'm not yet done with all of this investigation.

Can someone answer this specific question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to define a proper output operator(`operator<<`):

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int n;
    
    A() : n() {}
    
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &oss, const A &a) {
        oss << "[A]: " << a.n;
        return oss;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    boost::format f("%1%");
    std::cout << f % a << std::endl;
}
```